# Бесконечная генерация кривой CatmullRomSpline в LIBGDX

Tags: libgdx

**Вопрос:**

Позволяет ли CatmullRomSpline добавлять/удалять новые точки для генерации бесконечной незамкнутой кривой в процессе выполнения программы? Если позволяет, то как мне достичь такой генерации с учетом *исключения*, описанным ниже?

*К примеру:* в Vector2[] dataPoints инициализированы три точки. Через них проходит кривая. По кривой я перемещаю текстуру. Если текстура достигла половины кривой, то создать новую точку, провести через нее кривую, а пройденное расстояние удалить. Но есть [исключение](http://www.libgdx.ru/2015/02/math-utilities.html) в том, что начальная и конечная точки только контролируют построение кривой, но сама кривая через них может не проходит. Изображение для примера (рисовал "на глаз").

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код, который получилось написать по [туториалу](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Path-interface-and-Splines):

```
public class MyCatmullRomSpline {

private int mCountSections; //кол-во делений(точек) между основными точками указанными в dataPoints
private Vector2[] mSections; //массив делений
private ShapeRenderer mShapeRenderer;
private CatmullRomSpline<Vector2> mSpline;
private Vector2 out; 
private float speed; //скорость перемещения чего-либо по кривой


public GCatmullRomSpline(Vector2[] dataPoints, boolean closed, int countSections){

    speed = dataPoints.length - 1;

    mSpline = new CatmullRomSpline<Vector2>(dataPoints, closed);
    mSections = new Vector2[countSections];

    mCountSections = countSections;

    mShapeRenderer  = new ShapeRenderer();

    initSpline();
}

private void initSpline(){
    out = new Vector2();

    mSpline.valueAt(out, Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
    mSpline.derivativeAt(out, Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());

    for (int i = 0; i < mCountSections; ++i){
        mSections[i] = new Vector2();
        mSpline.valueAt(mSections[i], ((float)i)/((float)mCountSections-1));
    }
}

float current = 0;

public void render(SpriteBatch batch, Texture texture){
    mShapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);

    float derivativeAverage = 0;
    for (float i = 0; i < 1; i += 1f/mCountSections) {
        mSpline.derivativeAt(out, i);
        derivativeAverage += out.len();
    }
    derivativeAverage /= mCountSections;

    mSpline.derivativeAt(out, current);
    current += derivativeAverage / speed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() / out.len();
    current %= 1;

    if (current >= 1) current -= 1;
    mSpline.valueAt(out, current);

    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(texture, out.x - 18, out.y - 18, 36, 36);
    batch.end();


    for (int i = 0; i < mCountSections-1; ++i){
        mShapeRenderer.line(
                mSpline.valueAt(mSections[i], ((float)i)/((float)mCountSections-1)),
                mSpline.valueAt(mSections[i+1], ((float)(i+1))/((float)mCountSections-1)));
    }

    mShapeRenderer.end();
    }
}
```

Comment: А что значит - точки, через которые не проходит кривая? Для таких сплайнов это может быть только начальная и конечная точка последовательности. Или что-то ещё имеется в виду? И то, что в dataPoints[2] сшивка не гладкая - случайно или специально?

Comment: @MBo Да, особенность начальной и последней точки. А изображение - просто визуальное представление вопроса, любая неточность случайна.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала - сплайн Эрмита - кубическая кривая, которая задаётся начальной и конечной точками P(i), P(i+1) и производными в этих точках M(i), M(i+1)

Сплайн Кэтмулл-Рома - набор эрмитовых сплайнов, для обеспечения гладкости сшивки которых (гладкость первого порядка, т.е. в точках сочленения совпадают значения и наклон) используется простая зависимость - наклон в точке сшивки определяется равным наклону отрезка между двумя соседями этой точки (и амплитуда вектора производной может ещё нормироваться, но обычно используется просто номер точки, т.е. разность делится пополам)

```
M(i) = (P(i+1) - P(i-1)) / (t(i+1)-t(i-1))
```

Вот пример построения по точкам A,B,C,D,F

Направление в точке B определяется разностью C-A, в точке С - разностью D-B, в точке D - разностью F-C

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для построения одного КМ сплайна требуется 4 точки, двух - 5 точек, N - N+3 точек. *Можно достроить сплайны и до конечных точек, если задать какие-то дополнительные ограничения (например, кривизна, и соответственно вторая производная в конечной точке нулевая)*

Зная значение в некой точке кривой и производную в ней же (методы библиотека, как уже автор показал, предоставляет), мы можем разделить кривую на два сплайна. Данная точка станет стартовой точкой сплайна, а новую начальную точку последовательности можно перерассчитать, чтобы сохранить программный интерфейс в виде набора точек.

Но пока неясно, как это поможет генерировать бесконечную кривую.